# How to check if string element in i'th place in string is '\'?

Tags: python, string

How to check if part of the string is '\'. I'm having trouble since \ is a special symbol. In other languages this could be checked with something like s[i]=='\', but I am having no luck with Python so far.

Edit:Oh my bad, I meant \, don't know how this slipped up, sorry, edited now.

Comment: There's nothing special about `/`

Comment: There's nothing special about the forward slash... unless there's valid context you're not including.

Comment: Yeah, meant backslash, am tired...

Comment: Yeah, you should escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as in C or C++ or Java:

```
>>> s = 'abc\\abc'
>>> len(s)
7
>>> s[3] == '\\'
True
```

Comment: Thanks, worked, I guess I was seeing things when I tried this and it the IDE was complaining. Thanks again!